# Prevent middle click opening link

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I want to prevent middle click opening link, but only optional - in settings of chrome extension it can be set to prevent or not.

And when someone change that option (prevent or not) in settings of chrome extension it must affect immediately on the sites without reloading current pages (ctrl+r). To do this I put "chrome.runtime.sendMessage....." into "$(document).on("click...." to check out the value (true or not) of EnablePrevent (from local storage)". So it checks the value on every click (and I don't need to reload page ctrl+r to check the value).

Here is my code. I don't know how to get value (true) from block "chrome.runtime.sendMessage....." and I can't put block "if (e.button === 1..." into "chrome.runtime.sendMessage....." because prevent wouldn't work... (it needs "$(document).on("click....")

```
$(document).on("click", function(e) {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({method: "getLocalStorage", key: "EnablePrevent"}, function(response) {
        if (response.data == "true") {
            // ...
        }       
    });
    if (e.button === 1 && e.target.closest("a")) 
        e.preventDefault(); // not optional, always works..
    }
});
```

For Firefox's add-on it's not a problem:

```
var test = {
    MiddleClickListener : function(e) {
        if(e.button === 1) {
            var prefManager = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/preferences-service;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIPrefBranch);
            var EnablePrevent = prefManager.getBoolPref("extensions.EnablePrevent");

            if (e.target.closest("a") && EnablePrevent) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    }
}
window.addEventListener("click",test.MiddleClickListener,false);
```

Comment: Change the default behaviour of a browser is always a bad idea and will lead you to a lot of maintenances...

Comment: you should read your localStorage in content script and keep result in variable, so that when decision needs to be make, your code will read that variable. Sending message and waiting response to choose *what* is not good (too long). And when settings are changed, sendMessage to all scripts and rewrite that variable value, so that you have **fresh** data.

Comment: @user25 why not? In your content script, first thing you do is to fetch that value from storage and keeping it as global variable (for that tab). You don't use message system at all then. Your content script is loaded in every new tab, on tab reload etc... Is that right?...or am I missing something?

Comment: @WolfWar to get value in content_scipt.js from LStorage I have to use **chrome.runtime.sendMessag** and get response from background.js **chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener**. Next code: `var mdclicklink = localStorage["mdclicklink"]; if (mdclicklink == "play") alert("ok");` can be used only in background.js & options.js, but not in content_script. That's why Google added **chrome.runtime.sendMessag** && **method: "getLocalStorage"**  features

Comment: @user25 use **chrome.storage.local** for dealing with extension data. It's more faster (async), and you don't need to use stringify (or whatever methods to save objects, arrays..I totally forgot about limitation of HTML5 storage...sry). Then you can access it from your content script... Don't forget about storage permission

Answer (score 1, accepted):

waiting for messageResponse in click event is wrong logic
You should have **decision** prepared already in content script 
and to have that, use [Chrome storage API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage)

**manifest**

```
   "permissions": ["storage",.....]
```

**Options page**

```
    //on user changing option
    var EnablePrevent= ....//true or false 

    chrome.storage.local.set({'disableMMC': EnablePrevent});

    //to update it in real time, reroute it through background page
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({'user': 'choice', 'value': EnablePrevent});
```

**background page**

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function (message) {
    if (message.user=== 'choice') {
        var passValue = message.value;
        //send new value to all tabs
        chrome.tabs.query({}, function(tabs) {
            for (var i=0; i<tabs.length; i++) {
                chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[i].id, {'newValue': 'fromBG', 'newV':passValue});
            }
        });
    }
});
```

**Content script**

```
var disableMiddleButton;
chrome.storage.local.get('disableMMC', function(result) {
    disableMiddleButton = result.disableMMC;
});

//to update it in real time, listen for MSG from BG
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function (message) {
    if (message.newValue=== 'fromBG') disableMiddleButton = message.newV;
});

//use disableMiddleButton variable in your click logic

$(document).on("click", function(e) {
    if (disableMiddleButton  && e.button === 1 && e.target.closest("a")) 
        e.preventDefault();
});
```

---

another solution would be to listen storage changes in content script. In this case you don't need to send any message from Options page (or use rerouting through background page and have onMessage listener in Content script)

**Content script**

```
var disableMiddleButton;
chrome.storage.local.get('disableMMC', function(result) {
    disableMiddleButton = result.disableMMC;
});

//to update it in real time, listen for change in storage
chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener(function(changes, namespace) {
    if ('disableMMC' in changes) disableMiddleButton  = changes.disableMMC.newValue;
});

//use disableMiddleButton variable in your click logic

$(document).on("click", function(e) {
    if (disableMiddleButton  && e.button === 1 && e.target.closest("a")) 
        e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: I see it's really global var now, 50% of problem solved. I need to get the updated value when I click mouse, but now value is updated only if I reload page (ctrl+r) & then "prevent" works or not depending on what I set in extension's options. So **chrome.extension.onMessage** & **chrome.runtime.sendMessage** is useless here.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qpyk0ape/2/ (here options.js/html & content_script.js) - I'm trying put **chrome.storage.local.get** inside **$(document).on("click", function(e) {** What I have now: if I change "Enable Prevent" (true=checked label/false) in extension's options I get new value without reloading my current opened pages on click BUT on second try - on first click it's still the same value but on the second & the rest it's new value

Comment: @user25 Don't nest **storage.local.get** inside click event. There's no need for that really.  If you are worried about fresh state, that is taking care of with messaging from Options page. ------It doesn't work on first try because **chrome.storage.local** is *async API* (and the new state from storage is updated, but other part of the code is done by that time). You need to place **if** tests inside storage callback.... but like I said...it's better to use messaging...much lighter solution.

Comment: @user25 and **if(disableMiddleButton === true)** is the same as **if(disableMiddleButton)**

Comment: But If I don't put **storage.local.get** inside click event I won't get new value until ctrl+r, but if I put it will get (at least on second mouse click as you said "..but other part of the code is done by that time") & I still don't understand what is the point of using **onMessage/sendMessage**.. In any case (http://jsfiddle.net/pjqp06v9/1) I have to reload page to affect extension's option changes

Comment: @user25 the point of using message system from **options page** is that when user clicks on the button, options page will send new value (true or false), and content script will *hear* that message and change global variable accordingly so you don't have to read storage on click event to have **fresh state** ... you did right in http://jsfiddle.net/qpyk0ape/2/ for options page (just don't comment sending message when saving data to storage). In **content script** keep only **if** test in click event just like you did in second example with message http://jsfiddle.net/pjqp06v9/1/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85346/discussion-between-wolf-war-and-user25).

Comment: _options page will send new value_ I understand this, but _content script will hear that message_ it will hear only if I reload page) So it's enough to add only `storage.local.get` in that case. If I add `onMessage` to **content_script** and `sendMessage` to **options** there's still no difference (value updated only if I reload page & not updated on click event - on second or any else click) & I If don't use message it would be the same behavior (changes only on reloading page, so I don't need message if it changes on reloading page anyway). So the best way is to put local inside click event

Comment: @user25 I was wrong, only background can hear it, reroute it through background page, still better solution than onClick event...I'll update my answer... you get new value on reload because content script reads it from storage when loading

Comment: Thank you! It works good on first click now. Edit your answer (background page) and add one **}** before `}); });`

Comment: @user25 yea, I edited it... last solution (with *storage listener*) is the best in my opinion. You don't need any kind of messaging and doesn't involve background page (for this task). When you save something in **options page** any content script will be instantly updated.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(document).on("click", function(e) {
    var disableMiddleButton = 0;
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({method: "getLocalStorage", key: "EnablePrevent"}, function(response) {
        if (response.data == "true") {
            disableMiddleButton = 1;
        }       
    });
    if (e.button === 1 && e.target.closest("a") && disableMiddleButton == 1 ) 
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried it already. It doesn't work. "if( e.button === 1 ) {.." must be placed into "$(document).on("click", function(e) {"

Comment: whats the problem with first block of code you pasted? you can set a flag when `if (response.data == "true")` and use it to disable the button. i have edited my code for this.

Comment: Value can't be changed inside `chrome.runtime.sendMessag` . It's still "0"

Comment: test **if (e.button === 1 &&.....** doesn't wait for response from **sendMessage** (async method). it is always ´0´